# How do you turn on crontab logging on Big Sur?

Tags: launchd, big-sur, logs, cron

I am running macOS Big Sur 11.2.1 and have several crontab jobs set up and they work fine, but I want to turn on the logging of all of my crontab jobs.

I have read that with the recently releases such as Big Sur, macOS still supports crontab but not cron.  However I see I do have a cron process running:

```
0   274     1   0 12Feb21 ??         0:05.83 /usr/sbin/cron
```

But even though cron is running, /var/cron/log is nonexistent.

Some of my crontab jobs write to stdout which shows up in mail or mailx as I expect, but how do I turn on the logging of all of my jobs (start and end date/times, user, etc.)?

I see several questions and answers about how to turn on cron logging, but they all appear to apply only to earlier releases of macOS, not to Catalina or Big Sir.

Comment: Please add links to the claim about supporting crontab but not cron, and to the q&a's you've already looked at.